# where is 'thread_local' variable created in memory?

Tags: c++, c++11

where is the storage of `thread_local` variables in memory ? Is it `heap` ?

I have implemented a per-thread basis `bootstrap` function for our application, something like:

```
thread_local bool bootstrapped_ = false;
void Bootstrap()
{
    if (bootstrapped_)
        return;

    thread_local ContextTable contexts;
    contexts_ = &contexts;

    thread_local IndexMapper indexer;
    indexer_ = &indexer;
}

ContextTable* Contexts()
{
    if (!bootstrapped_)
        Bootstrap();
    return contexts_;
}

extern IndexMapper* Indexer()
{
    if (!bootstrapped_)
        Bootstrap();
    return indexer_;
}
```

In the source code above, where is the memory for variables `bootstrapped_` , `contexts` and `indexer` allocated ?

Comment: Why the obsession with "physical" location of variables in memory?

Comment: Heap and stack are implementation details.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition If these objects are allocated on StackFrame, then could there be possibility of StackFramSize not enough to hold the objects ?

Comment: @Monku: There's an easy way to find out, for your particular system and compiler.

Comment: The question asks where the thread local variables are stored. In the case of Windows, they are created outside of the normal heap and flat address space (for 64 bit mode accessed via segment register FS or GS (I don't remember which)). In some (or most?) cases, although the thread variables are effectively in a separate heap, they are mapped into each thread's address space.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition how is this question a duplicate ? The one you tagged is asking for the meaning. I am not asking that. I know what this storage specifier does. I am asking the details of its underlying implementation.

Comment: @Monku: And, if you read the answers there, you'll find out.

Comment: @rcgldr: Sometimes, maybe. But even if that were true for a particular implementation, and you could list all the occasions that it's true, it wouldn't be a C++ answer.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition my bad. got it :) thanks.